# mounting un-vented range hood in plaster and wood lath wall

Tags: kitchens

How best to fasten 30 pound range hood to wall - range hood has 2 large keyhole slots, I do not want to open the wall if possible.  Would conical anchors (#12 screws) and construction adhesive be sufficient?

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to overengineer this; you can imagine that having a (greasy) range hood come down over a source of heat and/or flame would be bad.

What if you drill-and-cut new keyhole slots to match where your studs are? I think you should be able to fit two of them in a range hood.

Note that this is probably only an acceptable solution if the studs are reasonably centered on the range hood.

Answer (score 0):

You could conceivably screw a range-hood-sized piece of something solid (preferably non-flammable or flame-retardant) to the studs, and hang the range hood on that.

I can't think of such a material that's easy to obtain and work with. Some sort of metal?